# Parse, format, and store as variable results from query

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I get this back:

```
array(1096) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["exuid"]=>
    string(36) "c056b5ce-3b0c-4494-858a-cf184b904dc3"
    [0]=>
    string(36) "c056b5ce-3b0c-4494-858a-cf184b904dc3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["exuid"]=>
    string(36) "8a6262c6-a4e0-41a4-8a47-ecaf5f79c2d5"
    [0]=>
    string(36) "8a6262c6-a4e0-41a4-8a47-ecaf5f79c2d5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["exuid"]=>
    string(36) "728cb9b6-6240-470f-87d5-706af554cd0b"
    [0]=>
    string(36) "728cb9b6-6240-470f-87d5-706af554cd0b"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["exuid"]=>
    string(36) "a26d0fdd-9a9b-4611-8c41-3d2c9b012988"
    [0]=>
    string(36) "a26d0fdd-9a9b-4611-8c41-3d2c9b012988"
  }  
    ETC
```

What I need to end up with is defining a variable that contains all the `exuid` returned separated by commas. Like this:

```
$something = 'c056b5ce-3b0c-4494-858a-cf184b904dc3', '8a6262c6-a4e0-41a4-8a47-ecaf5f79c2d5', '728cb9b6-6240-470f-87d5-706af554cd0b', 'a26d0fdd-9a9b-4611-8c41-3d2c9b012988'
```

I need it in this format to push into another query:

```
 where `exuid` in ($something)
```

But I can't parse this correctly. If I do `var dump($result)` I get the array shown above. If I do `var dump($result[0]['exuid'])` I get the first value back (c056b5ce-3b0c-4494-858a-cf184b904dc3), but not the others. How do I parse this and format it in the way I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the column and then join:

```
$something = "'" . implode("','", array_column($result, 'exuid')) . "'";
```

If you don't have PHP >= 5.5.0 then use this in place of `array_column()` :

```
array_map(function($v) { return $v['exuid']; }, $result)
```

Comment: I don't have PHP 5.5 or up. I tried the second one and got an array of the values, not a single string with them. Can I just pass this into my second query?

Comment: You replace the array_column part of the first code with the second code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$exuid = array();
foreach($result as $k=>$v)
{
    $exuid[] = $v['exuid'];
}
$exuid_str = "'" . implode($exuid, "','") . "'";

?>
```